# Dialog with native list and setemptyview

Tags: android

I have a FragmentDialog. In it's onCreateDialog method i create dialog using AlertDialog.Builder and .setAdapter(). This combination provides me simple single-choise list. But if there is no records in the database i get empty list with no items at all. How can i get dialog's list to use setEmptyView() method on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i get dialog's list to use setEmptyView() method on it?

You can fetch the Dialog's ListView like so:

```
ListView listView = ((AlertDialog) dialogFragment.getDialog()).getListView();
```

From here you can call `setEmptyView()` (or whatever else you want.)

Comment: right! i missed it. i was looking for such method in dialog class